# About to sell my 2013 rMac. Is 3 pass zero enough?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, secure-erase

I plan on selling my late 2013 rMBP  soon. I was wondering what your opinions are on me using a 3 pass zero on a SSD? Is it enough? I do have some sensitive data on there (bank info, passwords to important things at work, etc.). I also don't want to damage the SSD because I hear these passes can hurt the hard drive. Apple said that I don't even need to do that because SSD are just that great. Is that true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Apple's position is a standard erase is good enough on SSD. In the article on secure erasing, they recommend enabling FileVault before you ever introduce any sensitive data to the drive so that you can just throw away the encryption key and not need any passes of erase to be secure.

- http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201949

That being said, in your situation, I wouldn't do a 3 pass erase on an SSD and I also wouldn't do a simple erase with no passes.

Instead, I'd turn on FileVault 2 (Assuming you have a newer OS) and then boot to recovery mode and repartition the drive. Be sure to **not unlock the drive** but simply repartition it to an empty HFS+ partition, no passes needed.

That ensures that each writable block is totally encrypted and randomized so that it's impossible to tell what was free space and what was files, let alone do data recovery.

The passes are a marginal hit on the drive's life (they are rated for hundreds to thousands of passes), but one complete wipe might be as much wear as three months of heavy use. What makes the passes worthless is they waste your time and are un-necessary additional wear on a consumable part (the SSD).

Comment: Hello bmike, thanks for that information. I unfortunately never got to use FileVault to secure my files because I never used that program before. I do have the latest OS (yosemite). Is there a tutorial out there that describes step-by-step what you just said about using filevault before selling a mac? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes - open System Preferences and plug in your Mac to power. Then set it to not sleep in **Energy Saver** (screen can sleep, just keep the computer sleep to never). Lastly go to **Security & Privacy** and click on FileVault. Turn it on and wait for the encryption to finish. If this isn't enough, just ask a new question on the site and ping me with the link here.

Answer (score 1):

Three passes is akin to slamming on your brakes and screeching to a halt in your car. Your tires will be fine but you've just left a few hundred miles of rubber on the road. Chances are you hit the brakes for a good reason though so it was worth it.

You won't damage the SSD. Yosemite's 3 pass includes 2 passes of randomized data, which is very much like repartitioning the drive with FileVault turned on. There's little harm in even going to 7. Hopefully you encrypted sensitive data anyway. Recovering that won't do anyone any good assuming the encryption and password were fairly strong.

Comment: Total agreement. It's a lot of un-necessary wear for no real benefit, but SSD get replaced less often than tires on a vehicle.